# Mistakenly deleted OSM found on XYZ Tiles in QGIS Browser

Tags: qgis, xyz, xyz-tiles

I mistakenly deleted OSM found on XYZ Tiles how can I reset or restore it I tried to reinstall plugins but its not coming out even if I uninstall my software and download another one I can't find the drop down arrow to show OSM on XYZ Tiles.

Comment: Right click on XYZ Tiles and create a 'New Connection' with the following url: `https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`